# Align 2 (multiple) element in same equation

Tags: equations, align

I have a lot of equations which are too big to fit in a line, like this:

[image]

So basically I have to align '=' for a set of equations and '+' inside the equation when it enters a new line.

I'm trying to align the '=' signs in one column and the '+' signs in another, sort of like this:

[image]

I tried using split in align but that just makes it more deranged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, your best bet is to use `align*` for the outer alignment (the `=` signs), and `aligned` for the inner one (the `+` signs): this is because `\begin{aligned}`...`\end{aligned}` is designed to be nested within other kinds of display math. However, you also want to *vertically* align the inner one (at the pluses) with the outer one, so you'll write it as `\begin{aligned}[t]`...`\end{aligned}`.

Here's what it looks like in code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \begin{aligned}[t]
    a_1 &+ a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7\\
    &+ a_8 + a_9 + a_{10} + a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{13}\\
    &+ a_{14} + a_{15} + a_{16} + a_{17} + a_{18} + a_{19}
    \end{aligned}\\
A_2 &=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    a_2 &+ b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6 + b_7\\
    &+ b_8 + b_9 + b_{10} + b_{11} + b_{12} + b_{13}\\
    &+ b_{14} + b_{15} + b_{16} + b_{17} + b_{18} + b_{19}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solves the bigger problem. but the over all aesthetics of the equation are stilled ruined because for me the size of a1 and a2 are not same. is there any way to bring all the '+' in a column too ?

Comment: In that case, try putting the whole thing in an [`alignat`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Other_environments) environment, placing `&` at the `=` and column of `+` signs; that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 but you should add `\!` before each `aligned`

Answer (score 3):

As Arun Debray explained in his comment, use the `alignat` environment:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A_1 &=
    a_1 &&+ a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7\\
    &&&+ a_8 + a_9 + a_{10} + a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{13}\\
    &&&+ a_{14} + a_{15} + a_{16} + a_{17} + a_{18} + a_{19}\\
A_2 &=
    a_{222} &&+ b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6 + b_7\\
    &&&+ b_8 + b_9 + b_{10} + b_{11} + b_{12} + b_{13}\\
    &&&+ b_{14} + b_{15} + b_{16} + b_{17} + b_{18} + b_{19}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignat]